# MacBook keyboard repair program - India

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, warranty

I am planning to buy a MacBook Pro (2018) from Singapore for use in India. I want to know if my MacBook will be eligible for the keyboard repair program in India. If yes, how will I have to register the notebook for the keyboard repair program? (i.e. registration to be done in India or Singapore?)

The keyboard repair program as announced by Apple is supposedly "global". However, I am still not sure about the coverage in India since there is no webpage for the keyboard repair program under the `/in/` sub-website (while there is one on the `/sg/` website).

Comment: Please edit the answer or make your own answer once you find out. It reads as a global non-warranty free service. I would expect a delay for apple to publish articles in countries where it has no legal sales retail presence as Apple.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine. The service is available globally and can be availed by walking into any of the nearest authorized service provider in your city/state. The `/in/` subsection is not available on Apple's homepage because Apple doesn't yet have an online store/retail store in India.

Just search here:

- [Apple - Find Locations](https://locate.apple.com/in/en/)

Prefer visiting one of the Premium service providers. They generally maintain inventory or are able to procure parts in India. I am including an example search result from Bengaluru.

[image]

I do not have any document to link to, to support my claim. Speaking from personal experience.

Also, refer to this document from Apple:

- [Keyboard Service Program for MacBook, MacBook Air, and MacBook Pro - Apple Support - India](https://www.apple.com/in/support/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks/)

Comment: I’m not 100% sure about this - it will be great to hear this service is more generous than warranty as written and as implemented. Until Apple opens a retail presence in India, you are legally required to send your device back to the country where you purchased it for warranty service if Apple asks you to. Now, Apple and Apple warranty providers may choose to do the work under warranty in a different country if you ask them to. But they don’t have to and there are words in the warranty that say this very clearly last time I checked. I think you’re probably right, though.